# jquery scroll pagination infinite load of homepage

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm working on a timeline and I got some snippet of code to modify and use to my own taste. It gets the content from the database and whenever I go to a user's profile that hasn't posted anything the timeline loads the whole homepage inside the div allocated for it.

Here's the Jquery code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
/**
* Integrating slim scroll
**/
$("#ul").slimScroll({
    height: '1100px'
});
/**
* Integrating Scroll Pagination
**/
var feeds = $("#ul");
var last_time = feeds.children().last().attr('id');
feeds.scrollFeedPagination({
    'contentPage': '',
    'contentData': {
        'last_time' : last_time
    },
    'scrollTarget': feeds, 
    'beforeLoad': function(){
        feeds.parents('#feeds').find('.loading').fadeIn();
    },
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){
        last_time = feeds.children().last().attr('id');
        feeds.scrollFeedPagination.defaults.contentData.last_time = last_time;
        feeds.parents('#feeds').find('.loading').fadeOut();
        var i = 1;
        $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
    }
});
$.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity:1
        }, 200);
        delay += 100;
    });
};
//calling the function to update news feed
setTimeout('updateFeed()', 6000);
});
/**
* Function to update the news feed
**/
function updateFeed(){
    var id = 0;
    id = $('.li :first').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        'url' : '#feeds',
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : {
            'latest_news_time' : id  
        },
        success : function(data){
            setTimeout('updateFeed()', 6000);
            if(id != 0){
                $(data).prependTo("#ul");
                $(data).fadeIn("fast");
            }
        }
    }) 
}
</script>
```

I would like for it not to display no posts found or nothing at all. Thanks.

Comment: 'url' : '#feeds' seems fishy. What is the URL of the feed? Hash tags aren't server-side readable? Do you have a live demo? What's the website?

Comment: with or without the 'ur': '#feeds' it does the same thing. I don't want to make it live until it's perfect because the loop makes the system freeze a little. I'm thinking a sort of 'if' statement would do. Just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: then the problem might be on your server side. Idk. It's hard to tell with what we have.

Comment: just to show you what I'm experiencing. Pls visit this page http://ilon.org.uk/profile.php?user=dave . This is the timeline of a user with at least one post. Now go here http://ilon.org.uk/profile.php?user=dele . This the timeline of a user without a post. Check it and see how it responds.

Comment: Open your Developer Tools on chrome and under Network find profile.php?user=dave (the second one). This should be just user data... and it's the whole page. The demo doesn't use AJAX to load the content. It's rendered intially with the page by PHP. Disable JS to see it. Your ajax data format is completly wrong. It just reffers back to the page and since it's not JSON (but straigh html), nothing's loaded in both cases. If you're gonna do it, either do ajax pagination only or php pagination only (by refreshing).

Comment: ok. i wish i knew all what you are talking about but i just need a demo that's going to get new posts as they are posted without refreshing the whole page so i guess AJAX's the best bet. Also need the infinite scroll pagination.

Comment: I advice you get someone who's good with both php and jquery to fix it for you. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jsuHD/10/